# Lagging/glitching when moving things

Tags: modeling

When moving things, it almost seems like it's lagging or I'm moving in specific grids, it's hard to explain, watch the gif:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have snapping to increments while transforming on. Click on the magnet icon to turn it off, or change your snapping element (to vertex/edge/face) if applies.

[image]